# 'not a function error'

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I wrote the following logic

```
'use strict';
function F5 () {
}

F5.prototype.bang = function()
{
    console.log("pew pew");    
}

F5.bang();
```

execution falls short saying that 'F5.bang is not a function'

but it is. what did I write wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since F5 is a prototype, it must be initialized as an object in order to use prototype methods on F5. For example:

```
var abc = new F5();

abc.bang(); // pew pew
```

Comment: Or `F5.prototype.bang();` ;)

Comment: True, but I wouldn't recommend doing that if the prototype holds an actual object, since prototype methods are typically mutators.